# Append keys to existing array value

Tags: php, arrays, array-push

I have the following array and by using array_push & I am getting not the right result.

Array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1039
    [1] => 417
    [2] => 418
)
```

Array Push:

```
array_push($array, array("a","b","c"));
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1039
    [1] => 417
    [2] => 418
    [3] => Array
    (
        [0] => a
        [1] => b
        [2] => c
    )

)
```

I want the a,b,c append to value 417 for example .

Disirable result:

```
Array
(
    [1039] => 1039
    [417] => Array
    (
        [0] => a
        [1] => b
        [2] => c
    )
    [418] => 418

)
```

How can this be done?

SOLUTION:

```
$data = Array (
    0 => 1039,
    1 => 417,
    2 => 418,
 );

foreach( $data as $key => $val ) {
    $new_data[$val] = 0;
}

foreach( $new_data as $k => $v ){
    if( $k == 417 ){
        $new_data[$k] = array( 'p' => 50, 'pp' => 75 );
    }
}
print_r($new_data);
```

Comment: Your desired result isn't a valid PHP object. You can't have both a number and an array in the same array element.

Comment: Hi Barmar. I want to append to for example an array to value 417

Comment: You want to replace the value of `$array[1]` with an array? What do you mean by append?

Comment: I have 1 array and i want to add the other one to value 417. Is that possible?

Comment: You can't append an array to a number.

Comment: @Bas Is there a reason you'd actually want to do this?

Comment: I tried your "SOLUTION", it doesn't produce your desired output. Can you fix the question so it accurately describes what you want?

Comment: In your solution, all the values have become keys in the new array. Nothing like that was mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use loop to display new array data

```
 $data = Array (
      0 => 1039,
      1 => 417,
      2 => 418,
      );

 foreach( $data as $key => $val ) {
     if ( $val == 417 ) {
         $val = array( 'a','b','c' );
     }

     $new_data = array( $key => $val );
     foreach( $new_data as $key2 => $val2 ) {
         if ( is_array( $val2 ) ) {
             $val2 = array( 417 => $val );
         }
         $new_data1 = array( $key2 => $val2 );

    print_r($new_data1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Almost! Where is my number 417? I need that as well.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't really make sense, but this will do what you show in your example:

```
$array[1] .= print_r(array("a","b","c"), true);
```

`.=` does string concatenation, and passing `true` as the second argument to `print_r` makes it return the string that it would have printed.

The result of this is that `$array[1]` is a string that begins with `417` and is followed by the printed representation of the added array. There's no actual array in there. I'm not sure what you plan to do with this, but it matches your example.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use array push in this case (granted I might be missing your question)

```
$arr = array(1,2,3);
$arr[1] = array('a','b','c');
//would output your above example.
```

Comment: This replaces `417` with the new sub-array, it doesn't append it like in his desired result (which, granted, isn't actually possible).

Comment: Yeah, I agree his original isn't possible, so I was hoping and praying it was just a typo ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just do it like this & all should work as expected:

```
array_push($array, "a", "b", "c");
```

The [`array_push`](http://www.php.net/array_push) manual page explains it best:

```
$stack = array("orange", "banana");
array_push($stack, "apple", "raspberry");
print_r($stack);
```

But if the values you are adding are in an array already, then perhaps use [`array_merge`](http://www.php.net/array_merge) instead:

```
array_merge($array, array("a","b","c"));
```

Comment: This won't produce his desired result.

Answer (score 0):

My running php code:

```
$arr = array(0=>1039,1=>417,2=>418);
array_push($arr, array("a","b","c"));
var_dump($arr);
```

And var_dump($arr)

```
array(4) { [0]=> int(1039) [1]=> int(417) [2]=> int(418) [3]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(1) "a" [1]=> string(1) "b" [2]=> string(1) "c" } }
```

Comment: How is this different from what he does in his question?

Comment: Maybe You forgot something. Please type your code (not print_r($array)) or var_dump($array).

Answer (score 0):

Use `array_splice`

```
array_splice($your_arrray, 1, 0, array("a","b","c"));
```